# Copying Jquery Object which doesn't render

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV that I would like to manipulate without those manipulations appearing in the browser.  More specifically I'd like to remove a picture from a DIV and then save just the HTML.

```
divObj.find($(".picture1")).remove();
```

I tried techniques for copying divObj but even the copy referenced what was in the browser, so the above picture disappeared from the screen, which I don't want to happen.

So I first need to make a copy that does not really reference the DIV in the browser, but performs the action in memory only.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you pass an existing jQuery object (`$("#picture1")`) to `.find()`?

Comment: So do you want to remove the picture from the page but save it in some variable?

Comment: I want to remove the picture and save the rest.  As far as the Find goes, I didn't think it was relevant to the question.  It is a relic from edits I made to the original code before posting.

Comment: @Dave What exactly do you mean by *"save the rest"*?

Comment: Sorry... sending the rest to server to be saved using JQuery.Post().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I first need to make a copy that does not really reference the DIV in the browser, but performs the action in memory only. Is this possible?

Use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead of [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
var $copy = $("#picture1").clone();
```

`.find()` is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: I actually want to exclude the picture and take the rest.

Comment: Clone worked.  It made the changes in memory as I needed.  I'm sorry, I thought I had tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *extract* the picture from the document, but to store the jQuery object of the picture in some variable, you can use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method:

> The `.detach()` method is the same as `.remove()`, except that `.detach()`
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements.

```
var picture = $("#picture1").detach();
```

Comment: He doesn't want the element to disappear in the browser.

Comment: @Barmar That's how I interpreted this: *More specifically I'd like to remove a picture from a DIV and then save just the HTML*.

Comment: How did you interpret this: _picture disappeared from the screen, which I don't want to happen._

Comment: @Barmar And have you read the answer for [my question in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370480/copying-jquery-object-which-doesnt-render/14370557#comment19984579_14370480)? Quite straightforward: *I want to remove the picture and save the rest*. The question is uncertain. If `clone()` helped him, I guess he did `remove()` after cloning, which is absolutely the same as `detach()`. However it seems that my answer was not properly read.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to first need to make a div to store all this hidden stuff going on such as

```
<div class="myHiddenDiv"></div>
```

on

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.myHiddenDiv').hide();  //using jQuery's hide will hide , but allows changes
   });
```

then `clone()` the picture of thatever you want a copy of, `append()` this clone to the hidden div , and you can minapulate the hidden div all you want

Comment: Why do you need the hidden div? jQuery can manipulate detached elements just fine.

Comment: I was thinking he could clone the whole div , put it in a hidden parent , now when its hidden remove an image or whatever he wants , then he can copy this html without affecting what the user sees in their browser @Barmar